# Why was silver considered valuable in history?

Tags: history-of-chemistry, silver

Silver has been used for several millenia and (according to the german wikipedia page) was at some point even considered more valuable than gold. Today we know that it has the highest thermal conductivity and so on but these things were not known to the people back then.

What property made ancient civilizations agree that silver is something valuable compared to other metals like tin, gold or copper which were also known in the early days of humanity? Was is just rarity? Ductility? The ability to be polished? I assume that it was not just corrosion resistance as polished silver becomes dark rather quick.

Comment: It was fairly easy to separate, easy to work, and held up reasonably well. But this isn't really a chemistry question.

Comment: Well, I am asking about properties of silver that would have been known to ancient civilizations that justify this valuation.

Comment: Well, it was fairly easy to separate from the ores, was easy to work as a metal, and held up reasonable well in use. Only the first is chemistry, but the ancient civilizations had no idea of the actual chemistries of the ore and its separate.

Comment: Why people valued properties is not a chemistry question, but what those properties are *clearly* is. This should not be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was just about rarity.